# Run helper function in a hook only when some hook state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How can I adjust the code below so that the log message `console.log("This should log only on resetting the number")` is only logged when "Reset number" button is clicked, not when "Rerender" button is clicked?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const getNumber = () => Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

const useNumber = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number>(getNumber());

  const isLargerThan = React.useMemo(() => {
    const func = (i: number) => {
      console.log("This should log only on resetting the number");
      return value > i;
    };
    return func;
  }, [value]);

  const reset = () => setValue(getNumber());

  return { value, isLargerThan, reset };
};

const App = () => {
  const number = useNumber();
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = React.useState(false);

  console.log("rerendering");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Is {number.value} larger than 50?: {String(number.isLargerThan(50))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={number.reset}>Reset number</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTrigger(!trigger)}>Rerender</button>
    </div>
  );
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

LIVE EXAMPLE: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-playground-forked-2urxn2?file=/src/index.tsx:305-390

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are calling your `useCallback` function directly in your render method, so everytime you run a re-render, the function gets called once again. One way to avoid this would be to not have your useMemo return a function but rather a simple comparison. You could also initialize your hook with a value to store the number you are comparing to and use it at a `useMemo` dependency. I made something looking like this, which seems to be working as you intend.

```
const getNumber = () => Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

const useNumber = (val) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number>(getNumber());

  const isLargerThan = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log("This should log only on resetting the number");
    return value > val;
  }, [value, val]);

  const reset = () => setValue(getNumber());

  return { value, isLargerThan, reset };
};

const App = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(50)
  const number = useNumber(val);
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = React.useState(false);

  console.log(number.isLargerThan)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
  Is {number.value} larger than {val}?: {String(number.isLargerThan)}
      </div>
      <button onClick={number.reset}>Reset number</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setTrigger(!trigger)}}>Rerender</button>
    </div>
  );
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a really easy solution to achieve the desired result:

```js
  const isLargerThan = React.useCallback((i: number) => {
      console.log("updating the stored function");
      return value > i;
    }, [value]);
```

You should try `useCallback` because it will update the function you pass it *only* when `value` updates. Doing this you can call the function to display the right markup:

```js
<div>
  Is {number.value} larger than 50?: {String(number.isLargerThan(50))}
</div>
```

Comment: This is still breaking "rules of hooks"